# Make it possible for a jQuery appended label to toggle a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have a list with the following markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="element">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="toggler">
        <label for="checkbox1">Toggle +</label>
        <div class="more-info">
            <p>...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

The purpuse is to use pure CSS to make the toggle function, so I use this to hide/show the `<div class="more-info">...</div>`:

```
.more-info {
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

.toggler:checked ~ .more-info {
    max-height: 200px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Under the container, I have a button that will get (in this case it is static) element and append to the container. And this is where I have my problem, the label in the new element won't toggle the checkbox. If I make the checkbox visible and check it directly it works.

[I have also made a codepen to illustrate my problem](https://codepen.io/legarth/pen/boqYwo).

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues in your code. Firstly there's a `$a()` which should be just `$()`. You're also setting the class of the appended checkbox to `chekcbox` instead of `checkbox`. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $('#more').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var element, checkbox, label, moreInfo, dummyText;
    i++
    dummyText = $('<p />').text('Similique dis egestas aptent exercitationem sequi urna, nonummy laudantium, cillum pulvinar sociis assumenda? Minus nostra atque minima duis expedita ab irure sequi lectus natoque? Nihil. Similique dis egestas aptent exercitationem sequi urna, nonummy laudantium, cillum pulvinar sociis assumenda? Minus nostra atque minima duis expedita ab irure sequi lectus natoque? Nihil.');
    checkbox = $('<input />', {
      id: 'checkbox' + i,
      class: 'toggler',
      type: 'checkbox'
    });
    label = $('<label />', {
      for: 'checkbox' + i,
      text: 'Toggle +'
    });
    moreInfo = $('<div />', {
      class: 'more-info',
      html: dummyText
    });
    element = $('<div />', {
      class: 'element'
    }).append(checkbox, label, moreInfo);

    $('.container').append(element);
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #ededed;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggler {
  display: none;
}

.more-info {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ababab;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.more-info>p {
  margin: 0;
}

.toggler:checked~.more-info {
  max-height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
}

#more {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3498db;
  border: solid 2px #3498db;
  border-radius: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">
    <input id="checkbox1" class="toggler" type="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox1">Toggle +</label>
    <div class="more-info">
      <p>Similique dis egestas aptent exercitationem sequi urna, nonummy laudantium, cillum pulvinar sociis assumenda? Minus nostra atque minima duis expedita ab irure sequi lectus natoque? Nihil. Similique dis egestas aptent exercitationem sequi urna, nonummy
        laudantium, cillum pulvinar sociis assumenda? Minus nostra atque minima duis expedita ab irure sequi lectus natoque? Nihil.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="more">Get more</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! Was going mad. And all it was, was a typo.